# I drag and drop a Table View widget (Qt). How to resize it after filling the elements?

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, qt-creator

I am working in Ubuntu/c++ language.

I have the following QTable :

```
 ui1->tableView_->setVisible(false);
 QStandardItemModel *itemmodel_ = new QStandardItemModel(0,1);
 itemmodel_->setHeaderData(0, Qt::Horizontal, tr("File"));
  ui1->tableView_->setModel(itemmodel_);
//.. add new rows in the table

  ui1->tableView_->resizeColumnsToContents();
              ui1->tableView_->horizontalHeader()->setResizeMode(QHeaderView::ResizeToContents);

  ui1->tableView_plugin->setVisible(true);
```

After running the application the table is not resized. Where am I wrong? How to solve the problem?

And one more question: how to select an entire row in order to delete it after pressing a delete push button.

Appreciate.
THX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you didn't add your TableView to any layout. You need to add it to any layout in your form. For example:

```
QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout(this);
layout->addWidget(tableView);
```

Layout is a container for widgets. It purpose is adding positioning and resizing rules for its widgets. For example QVBoxLayout simply arranges widgets vertically. You can combine layouts with another layouts. So you can build complex UI designs simpler (with resize support). For further information you can check [this document](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/designer-layouts.html) and [this document](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/layout.html)

Comment: what is this layout? can i have one layout for all buttons tables that i have in yhe form?

Comment: where do i gave to add the layout line? in the method where i am filling the tableview?

Comment: You can define top level layout by selecting top level widget on designer and clicking any layout button (vertical, horizontal, grid etc.) (please look at first link of my answer) Then you can access this top level layout using [QWidget::layout()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qwidget.html#layout) at code.

Comment: +1 - Sounds silly (and it is), but I had the same bug.